# Taylor's series for multivariable function: not understanding some arguments

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I am following G. B. Folland's Advanced Calculus; the discussion below comes on p.90 of it.

Let $f$ be function from an open convex set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is $k$-th derivative continuous on $S$.

Fix $\mathbf{a}\in S$.

Consider $g(t)=f(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{h})$.

By chain rule, $g'(t)=\mathbf{h}\cdot \nabla f(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{h})$.

And hence $g^{(j)}(t)=(\mathbf{h}\cdot \nabla)^j f(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{h})$.

> **Q.** I didn't understand the precise meaning of last equation.
> To be precise in my question, I didn't get what is meaning of $(\mathbf{h}\cdot \nabla)^j$? I tried to understand it for $j=2$, but I couldn't! Can one explain what it says for $j=2,3$ in detail?

(I am trying to understand whether $\mathbb{h}\cdot \nabla$ is a function or operator? On what objects it is applied? What do we mean by taking its power? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an technically operator that takes a function to its $j$th derivative time and multiplies this function with $h^j$. Practically it is just an convenient way to write down, what happens if you derive $g$ for $j$ times:

This is just an application of the chain rule, where the inner function is $x(t) = a + th$, so $\frac{dx}{dt}=h$. Every time you derive, you are left with the derivative of the outer function and a factor of $h$.

Edit: As a general rule: If we write $K^j$ for an operator $K$ that means we  apply the operator $j$ times.